# Google OAuth 2: Obtain access and refresh tokens having offline token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate my server-side client using an offline code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API');
$client->setClientId('...');
$client->setClientSecret('...');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://');
$client->setDeveloperKey('...');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
$client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

$client->authenticate($offline_code));
```

outputs:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 
'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

 invalid_grant
 Bad Request
```

The credentials I'm using work fine for getting access and refresh tokens, but this requires user interaction. I have also double checked that offline token is issued to the same application. What else should I check?

Comment: Many possible explanations. There's a good post on SO that lists them. Try searching "invalid grant". Most common is that the Refresh Token you are sending is corrupt/missing. What is in $offline_code?

Comment: Theoretically I should be granted access having only offline token. $offline_code is that offline token. This should be very useful feature.  

 With help of access and refresh tokens I'm receiving data. But to get them I need to log in on server side using OAuth2. 

I have 2 ways:
1) Try to search why I can't authenticate having offline token
2) Obtain access and refresh tokens via user interaction and operate using them

Comment: Referring to the Google documentation, what is an "offline token"?